# Get result of the subscribe method of Flowable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I use a Flowable data in my method and I subscribe on it to get the result. I need to get the result from subscribe method in a way that I can make sure that the next instruction in my code will run immediately.

In my code I put the next instruction just after the subscribe method. Although I think it wont run synchronously.

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    var userForSave: User? = null
    if(responseCount(response) >= 2) {
        return null
    }
    userDao.getAll().map({ items -> items.first({ it.userName == user!!.userName} )})
        .subscribe({ res -> userForSave = res })
// I need to make sure that the next instruction after subscribe is this
    val tokenDto: TokenDto = TokenDto(token = userForSave!!.token, refreshToken = userForSave!!.refreshToken)
    val refreshTokenCall = service.refreshToken(tokenDto)
    val refreshResponse = refreshTokenCall.execute()
    if(refreshResponse.isSuccessful) {
        userForSave!!.token = refreshResponse!!.body()!!.token
        userForSave!!.refreshToken = refreshResponse!!.body()!!.refreshToken
        userDao.update(userForSave!!)
        return response.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${userForSave!!.token}")
            .build()
    }
    return null
}
```

I need to make sure that I can use "userForSave" for the next instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the first emission of the `Flowable` synchronously, you can call `blockingFirst()` instead of `subscribe(Consumer)`. In your case it should look like this:

```
userForSave = userDao
        .getAll()
        .map({ items -> items.first({ it.userName == user!!.userName} )})
        .blockingFirst()
```

Comment: Assume the result that will be saved in `userForSave` received after 4 seconds.  What happens if you try to print it exactly after that line?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. `blockingFirst` will block the execution in the Thread you're making the call from, if you print the value of `userForSave` right after the call to `blockingFirst` you will see the value returned from the Flowable. You will see the value after 4 seconds though.